# Make sure input is limited to variables

Tags: python, variables, input, python-3.x

I want to make sure that only the values specified in the 4 variables at the top get accepted and everything else user inputs gets rejected, how can I do this? Basically, I want the code to accept everything under Currency1, Currency2, Currency3 and Currency4. The problem with my code is that everything such as 'no', 'wdgdu' is being accepted. How can I limit the input to a those values under the 4 variables?

Comment: Perhaps just have ['yen'], ['euro'],['dollar','$'] etc. and use msg.lower()

Comment: But if I asked someone else to test this, it would give errors. I want to try and make it as user friendly as possible :)

Comment: `msg.lower()` will make the input entirely lower case, for example it would turn the input `'DoLlAR'` to `'dollar'`. My version is even more user friendly. ;)

Comment: Try the answers posted! they are doing exactly what you want.

Comment: I tried. But it seems that I cant check if the input value is definately in the variables AND that its not a float.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use:

- A dictionary to validate and normalize currency, rather than ad-hoc lists
- A loop to get valid input from the user, rather than recursion
- The `.lower()` method to normalize case

My refactored version:

```
CURRENCY = {
    '¥': 'JPY', 'yen': 'JPY', 'jpy': 'JPY',
    '€': 'EUR', 'euro': 'EUR', 'eur': 'EUR',
    '$': 'USD', 'dollar': 'USD', 'usd': 'USD',
    '£': 'GBP', 'pound': 'GBP', 'gbp': 'GBP',
}

def read_currency(prompt):
    """Prompt the user to enter a currency.

    Returns a currency code.
    """
    while True:
        x = input(prompt)
        try:
            return CURRENCY[x.lower()]
        except KeyError:
            print('Unknown currency: {!r}'.format(x))
```

You can then calculate conversion rates how you like:

```
from decimal import Decimal
RATES = { 
    'JPY': Decimal("0.010589"),
    'EUR': Decimal("1.2983"),
    'GBP': Decimal("1.5228"),
    'USD': Decimal("1.0000"),
}
def conversion_rate(cur1, cur2):
    """Get the conversion rate from currency 1 to currency 2."""
    return RATES[cur1] / RATES[cur2]
```

And here is code for the conversion:

```
amount = Decimal(input('Enter amount: '))
currency1 = read_currency('Enter source currency: ')
currency2 = read_currency('Enter target currency: ')
rate = conversion_rate(currency1, currency2)
print('{} {} is equal to {} {}'
      .format(currency1, amount, currency2, amount * rate))
```

Note that there are better rules for rounding you may want to apply.

Example run:

```
Enter amount: 1450
Enter source currency: yen
Enter target currency: $
JPY 1450 is equal to USD 15.3700
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, but the thing is, I need the whole list later on in the code. There will be many errors if I use your code^^

Comment: Apart from the fact that you should probably refactor your code to make this work (because this is a very tidy way to do it) you can just use CURRENCY.keys() to get your original list.

Comment: @jhoyla: You'll need `list(CURRENCY.keys())`, since this is Python 3, but that's right.

Comment: if Currency1 in CurrencyYen and Currency2 in CurrencyEuro:
                    Result = float(Amount*ExRate)
                    print(round(Amount,2),str('Yen'),str('is equal to'),"%.2f" %Result,str('Euros'),str('according to the current exchange rate.'))

That's the next bit of my code, so if I use teh method above, this will stop working and the coding will be a mess

Comment: @Jemini: Instead of `if currency1 in CurrencyYen`, you can just do `if currency1 == 'JPY'`

Comment: omg thanks SO much! :D you actually wrote the whole code for me, which is quite unfair as it has to be my own work BUT you now, if I combine my work with yours, it's going to be [PERFECT].

Comment: @DietrichEpp, omg thanks SO much! :D you actually wrote the whole code for me, which is quite unfair as it has to be my own work and I cant even combine your work with mine as the code above does not do error check and mine does. For your code above, how do i check if amount entered is definately in float, and if not, prompt and error?

Comment: @Jemini: Just like with the dictionary lookup where you could catch `KeyError` if it's not a known currency, with the conversion, you can catch `ValueError` if it's not a valid float.  Most conversion functions will throw `ValueError` in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

```
if currency in CurrencyYen + CurrencyEuro + CurrencyDollar + CurrencyPound:
    # do stuff
```

You [should](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) use lowercase for variable names

Also you can simply check `currency.lower()` and then you only need the lower case versions of each currency in the lists.

Comment: I'll change the name. :)
But.. if I use the if statement here, I wont be able to test both the currencies?

Comment: I need the code to reject a string such as 'yes' or 'sjkdh' . I meant.. I need to check both 'Currency1' and 'Currency2' separately. If Currency1 is not in the first 4 variables then the code should give an error?

Comment: ^ Yeah, I realised. I want the input to be limited as specified. :/

Answer (score 0):

If you use lower() on the input you don't need to keep both 'Dollar' and 'dollar'. Also you could use a while that never exists unless the correct input is entered. You could also use a quit command and break the while.

```
accepted_input = ['yen', 'euro', 'dollar', 'pound', '$']

def get_currency(msg):
    input_valid = False
    while not input_valid:
        user_input = input(msg).lower()
        input_valid = user_input in accepted_input
    return user_input

currency_from = get_currency('Convert from: ')
currency_to = get_currency('Convert to: ')
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use a For to check the user input:

```
CurrencyYen = ['Yen', 'yen', 'YEN']
CurrencyEuro = ['Euro','euro','EURO']
CurrencyDollar = ['Dollar','dollar','DOLLAR','$']
CurrencyPound = ['Pound', 'pound', 'POUND','£']

UserInput = raw_input("Value: ")

for i in range(0,2):
    if (UserInput == CurrencyEuro[i]):
        print "correct input!"
        break
    else:
        print "wrong input"
```

Same code for all the other lists.

Comment: Use `for i in CurrencyEuro`, and this is reimplementing functionality already in python.

Comment: i.e. `if UserInput in CurrencyEuro` does this for free.

Comment: Thanks @LStyle, The code works, but I have to provide both input. I want it to break off if Currency1 is not there.

Comment: @jhoyla, yes, I tried that already :) but again, I want to to break off BEFORE asking for Currency2

Comment: Do you mean that if the first value in the list will not be the UserInput it will stop checking the other values in the list?

Comment: Ah, I think you want 
`try:` 
    `currency_1 = get_currency() `
    `currency_2 = get_currency() `
`except: `
    `print 'oops'`

Comment: Basically BOTH calls of `get_currency` must be in a single `try` block.

Comment: @LStyle, no i mean, that if the first value that the user inputs is NOT in the list then the code willstop.

Comment: I imagine that's because you're catching the exception **INSIDE** the `try` block, try removing the other `try catch` blocks.

Comment: How did you know? ^ And, But how do I do a float check?

Comment: Use `catch ValueError` to catch only 'not a float' exceptions.